# read values from excel and stored in listcollection of type viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am writing a c# code that is using DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.5.0 library to read the values from an excel file. The excel has three columns. My program needs to read three columns values and store the value in List collection that returns an `IEnumerable<ShipViewModel>`

My View model basically contains three properties. See code below

```
public class ShipViewModel
{

    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }

}
```

Logic to read the excel file

```
 public List<ShipViewModel> OpenSpreadsheetDocument(string filepath)
        {

            List<ShipViewModel> model = new List<ShipViewModel>(); 

            // Open a SpreadsheetDocument based on a filepath.
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
                SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
                string text;
                foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
                {
                    foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
                    {
                        text = c.CellValue.Text;
                        Console.Write(text + " ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am looking at populating the list collecting in the for loop. See code below for example.
But if you check the loop above, Column2 and Column3 will contain the same cell value of Column1 which should not be case. The value of the cell only changes during the next iteration.

```
 ShipViewModel shipViewModel = new ShipViewModel();
                    shipViewModel.Column1  = c.CellValue.Text;
                    shipViewModel.Column2   = c.CellValue.Text;
                    shipViewModel.Column3  = c.CellValue.Text;

                    model.Add(shipViewModel);
```

Comment: are you using Interop.Excel?

Comment: Hi Aravind. I am using DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.5.0

Comment: What if you dropped the cell for loop, since you know how many cells are affected, and do a mapping to the shipViewModel.Column#'s based on what you have in r. (where you have the text=...)

Comment: Could you explain. Didnt get you

Comment: You will need to get the first `Cell` and set `Column1` to its value, the repeat for the 2nd cell etc. But if would probably be easier and more flexible if you view model contained a property `List<string> Columns` rather that 3 individual properties

Answer (score 0):

I can  show you my solution how to import data from Excel to database, you have to install LinqToExcel from nuget.
Here is code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadExcel(Item items, HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {

        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        if (FileUpload != null)
        {
            // tdata.ExecuteCommand("truncate table OtherCompanyAssets");  
            if (FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {


                string filename = FileUpload.FileName;
                string targetpath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Excel/");
                FileUpload.SaveAs(targetpath + filename);
                string pathToExcelFile = targetpath + filename;
                var connectionString = "";
                if (filename.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", pathToExcelFile);
                }
                else if (filename.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", pathToExcelFile);
                }

                var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);
                var ds = new DataSet();

                adapter.Fill(ds, "ExcelTable");

                DataTable dtable = ds.Tables["ExcelTable"];

                string sheetName = "Sheet1";

                var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile);
                var artistAlbums = from a in excelFile.Worksheet<Item>(sheetName) select a;

                foreach (var a in artistAlbums)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (a.Name != "" && a.Description != "" && a.Number != "")
                        {
                            Item TU = new Item();
                            TU.Name = a.Name;
                            TU.Description = a.Description;
                            TU.Number = a.Number;
                            db.Items.Add(TU);

                            db.SaveChanges();



                        }
                        else
                        {
                            data.Add("<ul>");
                            if (a.Name == "" || a.Name == null) data.Add("<li> Name is required</li>");
                            if (a.Description == "" || a.Description == null) data.Add("<li> Description is required</li>");
                            if (a.Number == "" || a.Number == null) data.Add("<li>Number is required</li>");

                            data.Add("</ul>");
                            data.ToArray();
                            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                        }
                    }

                    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                    {
                        foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                        {

                            foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                            {

                                Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                //deleting excel file from folder  
                if ((System.IO.File.Exists(pathToExcelFile)))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(pathToExcelFile);
                }
                return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                //alert message for invalid file format  
                data.Add("<ul>");
                data.Add("<li>Only Excel file format is allowed</li>");
                data.Add("</ul>");
                data.ToArray();
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            data.Add("<ul>");
            if (FileUpload == null) data.Add("<li>Please choose Excel file</li>");
            data.Add("</ul>");
            data.ToArray();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```